# Speeding up large data graph query and rendering with AMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, active-model-serializers

I have a query that spans multiple tables which in the end uses Active Model Serializers to render the data. Currently a large portion of the time is spent in the serializers since I am forced to query some of the data from within the serializer itself. I want to find a way to speed this up, and that may be not using AMS (this is okay).

My data model is as follows:

```
Location
  -> Images
  -> Recent Images
  -> Days Images
Image
  -> User
```

The `recent_images` and `days_images` are the same as the `images` but with a scope to do a `where` to filter by days and `limit` to 6.

Currently this whole process takes about 15 seconds locally and 2-4 seconds in production. I feel like I can perform this much quicker but am not entirely sure how I can modify my code.

The query to fetch the `Location`s is:

```
ids = @company
  .locations
  .active
  .has_image_taken
  .order(last_image_taken: :desc)
  .page(page)
  .per(per_page)
  .pluck(:id)
Location.fetch_multi(ids)
```

`fetch_multi` is from the [identity_cache](https://github.com/Shopify/identity_cache) gem. These results then hit the serializer which is:

```
class V1::RecentLocationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  has_many :recent_images, serializer: V1::RecentImageSerializer do
    if scope[:view_user_photos]
      object.fetch_recent_images.take(6)
    else
      ids = object.recent_images.where(user_id: scope[:current_user].id).limit(6).pluck(:id)
      Image.fetch_multi(ids)
    end
  end

  has_many :days_images do
    if scope[:view_user_photos]
      object.fetch_days_images
    else
      ids = object.days_images.where(user_id: scope[:current_user].id).pluck(:id)
      Image.fetch_multi(ids)
    end
  end
end
```

The scopes for recent and days images is:

```
scope :days_images, -> { includes(:user).active.where('date_uploaded > ?', DateTime.now.beginning_of_day).ordered_desc_by_date }
scope :recent_images, -> { includes(:user).active.ordered_desc_by_date }
```

My question is if you think I need to ditch AMS so I don't have to query in the serializer, and if so, how would you recommend to render this?

Answer (score 1):

I may have missed the point here - what part is slow? What do the logs look like? Are you missing a db index? I don't see a lot of joins in there, so maybe you just need an index on date_uploaded (and maybe user_id). I don't see anything in there that is doing a bunch of serializing.

You can easily speed up the sql in many ways - like, a trigger (in ruby or sql) that updates the image with a user_active boolean so you can dump that join. (you'd include that in the index)

OR build a cached table just with the IDs in it. Kind of like an inverted index (I'd also do it in redis, but that's me) that has a row for each user/location that is updated when an image is uploaded.

Push the work to the image upload rather than where it is now, viewing the list.

Comment: The slow part of the query is that the serializer has to perform the fetch and so it ends up performing an N+1 query. The query for the locations is easy, but the serializers then performs a query for each of the locations, 1 for days images and 1 for recent images. It balloons quickly, and I was hoping to find a easier solution

Comment: right, my point stands - once you have a big enough 3-way query like this, you build a table that represents all search results, that you update when a user uploads an image. Assuming relatively few images being uploaded and lots of queries, you optimize for queries and do the work of 'search' on upload, with triggers/callbacks that insert the image into all the search result tables.

Comment: you may be able to do this with some clever thing but that will bite you later. make a new model that represents a search result and make a bunch of them. models are cheap, code complexity and hacks are hard (for future-you).